# What VHDL datatype should I use for a memory address?

Tags: vhdl, type-conversion

I'm developing a description of a BIST engine, and I've been asked by my manager to transition from Verilog to VHDL. I'm very rusty with VHDL, and I can't figure out the right datatype to give to the address register in my code. Most of the time, the address is used to index into arrays.

```
data : std_logic_vector (2**W-1 downto 0);
...
output = data(addr);
```

Sometimes though, I need to perform bitwise operations (for example, this code that finds the least-significant 1 in the address):

```
least_one(0) <= addr(0);
PRIORITY_ENCODER : for i in 1 to (W-1) generate
    least_one(i) <= addr(i) and not or_reduce(addr(i-1 downto 0));
    end generate PRIORITY_ENCODER;
least_one(W) <= not or_reduce(addr);
```

Finally, I also rely on the address wrapping around without problem when it overflows (i.e. 1111+1 = 0, and 0-1 = 1111).

So, given all these different uses, what datatype or subtype do I give to the address? When I use integer and the related types, I get errors when I perform the bitwise operations:

```
ncvhdl_p: *E,APNPFX (filename,17|20): can not make sense of P(...)
```

When I use std_logic_vector or similiar, I get errors trying to use the address as an array index:

```
ncvhdl_p: *E,INTYMM (filename,52|17): array index type mismatch [6.4]
```

I seem to be in a no-win situation here. What data type do I use? Please note, the solution must be synthesizable. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want bitwise access and wrapping behaviour:

- make `addr` fundamentally an `unsigned` vector.

Then you need access to it as an integer:

- If you need it as an integer on just one line, use the `to_integer` call on just that line.
- If you need it as an integer in more than one place, create another signal to "shadow" it and put a continuous assignment in the architecture

Like this:

```
signal addr_int:natural;
....
addr_int <= to_integer(addr);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use `unsigned` type.

This will work very similar to how you are used to `std_logic_vector` operating in terms of generic bit access, but you can also do arithmetic operations on the address and easily convert to/from `integer` type, if necessary. Plus it doesn't dirty the sense of `std_logic_vector` with the "dreaded" `std_logic_unsigned` package.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

...

architecture myarch of myent is
   signal address : unsigned(numbits-1 downto 0);

   ...

begin

-- as an example
addr_counter : process(sysclk, reset)
begin
   if reset = '1' then
      address <= (others => '0');
   elsif rising_edge(sysclk) then
      address <= address + 1;
   end if;
end process addr_counter;
...
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve the _array index type mismatch_ error. I can't use an unsigned to index a vector, and constantly converting to integer isn't really an option because the address is mostly used as a index. I'd really like a datatype that would avoid conversion all together.

Comment: what I mean is, I don't want dozens of `to_integer(address)` statements littering up my code, since in the majority of references to address I use it as an index. I could make it an int and convert to unsigned when necessary, but then I run into the problem where the signal won't overflow right. Guess I'll write my own addition function, but all this seems like way too much trouble; should be a simpler way.